# Add group to Library permissions using powershell

Tags: document-library, permissions, powershell, groups

I have written a script that created a document library called "Audit Logs" for every site collection in our environment.  I then wanted to ensure that only Site Collection administrators and the individual site Owners group had access to this document library.  I was able to write a script to break the inheritance, allowing only the site collection administrators to view the library.

I was told after the fact that I also needed to make sure the the Owners group was able to access the Audit logs as well.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$site = Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb -limit all | ForEach-Object {
$listName = "Audit Logs"


$list = $_.Lists[$listName]
$list.BreakRoleInheritance($False)

$list.Update()
}
```

How do I add the Owners group to the ACL for each of the Audit Log folders?  I have seen various methods for adding individual user accounts, but not for a group.

I am using powershell and Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This script should do the trick after few adjustments as its adding new permissions to group which you don't want so you can skip them.

```
function Add-SPPermissionToListGroup
{
    param ($Url, $ListName, $GroupName, $PermissionLevel)
    $web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Url
    $list = $web.Lists.TryGetList($ListName)
    if ($list -ne $null)
    {
        // Ensure that the permissions are not being inherited.
        if ($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $False)
        {
            $list.BreakRoleInheritance($True)
        }

        // Modify the permissions.
        if ($web.SiteGroups[$GroupName] -ne $null)
        {
            $group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
            $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
            $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
            $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);
            $list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
            $list.Update();
            Write-Host "Successfully added $PermissionLevel permission to $GroupName group in $ListName list. " -foregroundcolor Green
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host "Group $GroupName does not exist." -foregroundcolor Red
        }

    }
    $web.Dispose()
}
```

[Source](http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/using-powershell-to-work-with.html)

Comment: Thank you!  This has given me a good idea how to work out my solution!

Comment: if ($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $False) { ... } else { ... } - why? With your code, if the list inherits permissions, you will break the inheritance and abort the operation. Why abort it?

Comment: how can i apply the permissions to a single user?  if i try with a single user instead of group, it failed! $musername ="domain1\\muser1" , when i tried with this, it throws error

Comment: > new-object : A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment.
At E:\PoCSolutions\BreakRoleInheritance_HISTORY1List.ps1:30 char:31
+             $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($ 
+                               
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : annotFindAppropriateCtor,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Answer (score 4):

Just an addendum to this as I came across this post while researching an issue we were having, if you call $List.Update() right after the RoleAssignments.Add(), you may hit a race condition and it'll report a save conflict on the $List item.

it will however update the RoleAssignment as the .Add commits the change without the need to call .Update() on the list.

Paul.

Comment: I think this has been an issue with CSOM managed code as well. I had these kind of errors (in less than 1% of cases) 4-5 months back, however did not know enough of SharePoint to find the root cause at that time. Maybe I still don't know enough. Any chance there are any references/documentation for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, TimeToShine.  I appreciate you posting that script, it definitely helped get me to where I needed to be.  Here was my final script:

```
if ( -not $(Get-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue" )) {Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell}

$sites = Get-SPSite | Select RootWeb, URL

foreach ($site in $sites){

$ListName = "Audit Logs"
$PermissionLevel = "Full Control"
$web = $site.rootweb
#$web = Get-SpSite -identity $site.url
#$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $site.url        
$list = $web.Lists | where {$_.Title -match $ListName}
    if ($list -ne $null)
    {
        if ($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $False)
        {$list.BreakRoleInheritance($True)}

        if ($list.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $True)
        {
            ForEach ($SiteGroup in $web.SiteGroups) {                    

                if ($SiteGroup.Name -match "Owners")
                {
                    #write-host $SiteGroup.Name
                    $GroupName = $SiteGroup.Name
                    $roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($SiteGroup)
                    $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
                    $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);
                    $list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
                    $list.Update();
                    Write-Host "Successfully added <$GroupName> to the <$ListName> list in <$site>. " -foregroundcolor Green
                }                
                else
                {
                     Write-Host "No Owners groups exist." -foregroundcolor Red
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
```