# Configure permissions on documents libraries

Tags: permissions, document, libraries

First of all, i want to apologize for my english :) Im just a french student.

I work on SP 2013 for 3 weeks now. I'm using it with powershell. I have to write a script that will create web app, sites collection, subsite on 2 levels, and finally document libraries. I have to set permissions for several users, on each library, in powershell.

The `New-SPUser` and `Set-SPUser` do not work with a library's url.

So I found things like this [Add group to Library permissions using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58293/add-group-to-library-permissions-using-powershell).

EDIT : I succeeded in creating the good rights for my user on a document library which is not in a subsite.

So I thought I can do the same, by using `Get-SPWeb` instead of `Get-SPSite`, but no.

So I'm still not able to set permissions on a subsite's document library =/ and by the way, i can't add users/groups to set their permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found something interesting. I'll test it and come back if it's the solution : 
http://urlmin.com/qye

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://sp-2010
$account = $web.EnsureUser("SHAREPOINT\mray")
$role = $web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"]

$list = $web.Lists["Shared Documents"]

$list.BreakRoleInheritance($true)

$assignment = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($account)
$assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($role)
$list.RoleAssignments.Add($assignment)

$list.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to break inheritance before you are able to change permissions for a SPWeb. Refer to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee547386.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already done this, with

$list.BreakRoleInheritance($true)

Comment: Do you mean I have to do this for subsites ??

Comment: It depends on your requirements. In your example you broke inheritance at the list level only. If you needed to change permissions for a sub-site you would to the same for the respective SPWeb object.

Comment: Hum ok, That's clever :D I think the problem comes from the fact that I have lists in subsites... And i want so set permissions for each lists. I'll test it asap, and post if I find something interesting. Thank you @Miguel Lima