# Powershell - creating document libraries and wish to add an existing group

Tags: 2010, document-library, powershell, permissions

I have a powershell script I developed in order to create document libraries across multiple sites under a single site collection.  I wish to now add the appropriate Site Administrators with appropriate permissions to the document library, and am having a little difficulty in finding the appropriate group name in order to add it.
This is what I have thus far.  It will create the document library and I managed to display any Sharepoint group that has a string match to what I am looking for, but this seems too prone to error.  I also do not know how to actually add the group once I have properly grabbed it.

```
$listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::DocumentLibrary
$listURL = "mydoclib"
$listTitle = "Document Library"
$listDescription = "Document Library"

$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://site.com/aboutme"
  foreach($subWeb in $spWeb)
  {
  if($subWeb -ne $null)
  {
    Write-Host $("Site: "+$subWeb.URL)

    $SiteRoles = $subWeb.RoleAssignments
    foreach($role in $SiteRoles)
    {
      write-Host $role.Member.Name -foregroundcolor "yellow"
      if ($role.Member.Name -like "*Admin*")
      {
        write-host $role.Member.Name -foregroundcolor "cyan"
      }
    }
    ####CREATE
    $subWeb.Lists.Add($ListUrl,$ListDescription,$listTemplate)
    $list = $subWeb.Lists[$listURL]
    $list.Title = $ListTitle
    $list.OnQuickLaunch = $True
    $list.Update()
    $subWeb.Dispose()
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Output $($subWeb + "does not exist")
  }
}
```

How would I go about properly grabbing any SharePoint group with the "TeamSite Administrator" permission level (a custom permission level) and apply it to the newly created Document Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *break* the permission of the list, create a new role and assing it the to group.
Then assign the role to the list.

```
$list.BreakRoleInheritance($True)
$group = $web.SiteGroups[$GroupName]
$roleAssignment = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment($group)
$roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
$roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);
$list.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment)
$list.Update();
```

Have a look here [Add group to Library permissions using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58293/add-group-to-library-permissions-using-powershell)

Comment: Thank you for your reply - this works wonderfully.  The solution provided assumes I have a group name already to work with.  Would you happen to know how I can grab a group with specific permission levels on the specific site I am working with?  Since I am iterating through sites, I do not have a method to grab specific group names prior to applying them.  For example, I would like to grab the "About Me Administrators" group (if I am currently iterating that site) which has the "TeamSite Administrators" permission level and only apply that group to the newly created document library

Comment: nevermind i found a way :)  I mistakenly assumed I needed to ADD the group, but it gets created with inherited permissions anyways, so I actually needed to REMOVE the groups I'm NOT interested in.  Using code found here I finalized my solution.  Thanks!
http://sharepointthinking.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/how-to-remove-users-and-groups-from-a-sharepoint-list-using-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You can get site collection admins from powershell as:

```
foreach($siteAdmin in $site.RootWeb.SiteAdministrators)
```

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/PowerShell-Script-for-aeba93d8

http://sharepointhangout.com/powershell-script-to-display-site-collection-administratorsprimary-secondary/

Comment: I am actually looking to grab site administrators for a specific site with a specific permission level - not the site collection admins.